# Grep multiple strings and then replace text

Tags: unix, sed, grep, varnish

I have below varnish command:

```
sudo varnishlog -c
```

and its output

```
*   << Request  >> 658516
-   Begin          req 658515 rxreq 
-   ReqMethod      GET
-   ReqURL         /sample/2 
-   VCL_call       HIT
-   RespHeader     X-Timestamp: 1460482977.61998
-   RespHeader     X-Varnish: 658516 658416
-   RespHeader     X-Varnish-Cache: HIT
```

From this command output I want to redirect the output to a file with following fomat:

```
Begin="req 658515 rxreq",ReqURL="/sample/2", RespHeader="X-Varnish-Cache: HIT"
```

I have used grep command to get the required fields:

```
sudo varnishlog -c | grep -E 'Begin|ReqURL|Varnish-Cache'

-   Begin          req 658515 rxreq 
-   ReqURL         /sample/2
-   RespHeader     X-Varnish-Cache: HIT
```

But if I used additional commands to replace space and new lines I am facing issue.

```
sudo varnishlog -c | grep -E 'Begin|ReqURL|Varnish-Cache' | sed 's/ /=/g'
```

With this command I am not getting any output.

If I use sed or tr commands:

```
sudo varnishlog -c | sed 's/ /=/g'
```

or

```
sudo varnishlog -c | tr ' ' '='
```

Then output is :

```
*===<<=Request==>>=629459====
-===Begin==========req=629458=rxreq
-===ReqMethod======GET
-===ReqURL=========/sample/2
-===VCL_call=======HIT
-===RespHeader=====X-Varnish-Cache:=HIT
```

If I use this:

```
sudo varnishlog -c | sed 's/\t/=/g'
```

Then output is same as original :

```
*   << Request  >> 658516
-   Begin          req 658515 rxreq 
-   ReqMethod      GET
-   ReqURL         /sample/2 
-   VCL_call       HIT
-   RespHeader     X-Timestamp: 1460482977.61998
-   RespHeader     X-Varnish: 658516 658416
-   RespHeader     X-Varnish-Cache: HIT
```

please help me with some hints on what is the correct way to get my required output.

**@Sundeep,** Perl version on my machine is :

```
 perl -version

This is perl 5, version 18, subversion 2 (v5.18.2) built for x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi
(with 44 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail)
```

@Sundeep,

Output of `sudo varnishlog -c | cat -A`

```
$
*   << Request  >> 363192    $
-   Begin          req 363191 rxreq$
-   Timestamp      Start: 1478514424.525802 0.000000 0.000000$
-   Timestamp      Req: 1478514424.525802 0.000000 0.000000$
-   ReqStart       10.56.36.2 52583$
-   ReqMethod      GET$
-   ReqURL         /sample/2$
-   ReqProtocol    HTTP/1.1$
-   ReqHeader      Host: localhost:6081$
-   ReqHeader      User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu;....$
-   ReqHeader      Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8$
-   ReqHeader      Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5$
-   ReqHeader      Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate$
-   ReqHeader      Connection: keep-alive$
-   ReqHeader      Pragma: no-cache$
-   ReqHeader      Cache-Control: no-cache$
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: 10.56.36.2$
-   VCL_call       RECV$
-   VCL_return     hash$
-   ReqUnset       Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate$
-   ReqHeader      Accept-Encoding: gzip$
-   VCL_call       HASH$
-   VCL_return     lookup$
-   Hit            658416$
-   VCL_call       HIT$
-   VCL_return     deliver$
-   RespProtocol   HTTP/1.1$
-   RespStatus     200$
-   RespReason     OK$
-   RespHeader     Content-Length: 4774$
-   RespHeader     Last-Modified: Tue, 12 Apr 2016 17:42:58 GMT$
-   RespHeader     Etag: f9d34a65e8c1b30245c2f12534348ff9$
-   RespHeader     X-Timestamp: 1460482977.61998$
-   RespHeader     Content-Type: image/png$
-   RespHeader     X-Trans-Id: txf52283ea65004e578ddfe-0058203d84$
-   RespHeader     Date: Mon, 07 Nov 2016 08:38:28 GMT$
-   RespHeader     X-Varnish: 363192 658416$
-   RespHeader     Age: 6516$
-   RespHeader     Via: 1.1 varnish-v4$
-   VCL_call       DELIVER$
-   RespHeader     X-Varnish-Cache: HIT$
-   VCL_return     deliver$
-   Timestamp      Process: 1478514424.525880 0.000078 0.000078$
-   RespHeader     Accept-Ranges: bytes$
-   Debug          "RES_MODE 2"$
-   RespHeader     Connection: keep-alive$
-   Timestamp      Resp: 1478514424.525908 0.000106 0.000028$
-   ReqAcct        415 0 415 394 4774 5168$
-   End            $
```

Comment: or a simpler `perl -ne 'if(/Begin|ReqURL|Varnish-Cache/){ s/^-\s*//; s/^\S+\K\s+(.*\S)\s*/="$1",/; print}' | sed 's/,$/\n/'`

Comment: @Sundeep, I tried your command - `sudo varnishlog -c | perl -ne 'if(/Begin|ReqURL|Varnish-Cache/){ s/^-\s*//; s/^\S+\K\s+(.*\S)\s*/="$1",/; print}' | sed 's/,$/\n/'`, I am not seeing anything in output

Comment: @Sundeep, the command `sudo varnishlog -c | perl -ne 'print if(/Begin|ReqURL|Varnish-Cache/)'` is working same as like `grep`. I updated my post with my perl version.

Comment: see if sed works.. `sed -nE '/Begin|ReqURL|Varnish-Cache/ {s/^-\s*//; s/^(\S+)\s+(.*\S)\s*/\1="\2"/; p}' | paste -sd,` .. use `-r` if your sed doesn't support `-E`

Comment: @Sundeep, tried this - `sudo varnishlog -c | sed -nE '/Begin|ReqURL|Varnish-Cache/ {s/^-\s*//; s/^(\S+)\s+(.*\S)\s*/\1="\2"/; p}' | paste -sd`  but getting error as `paste: option requires an argument -- 'd'`

Comment: I added it now, this time I am getting empty output :(

Comment: do you have some strange line endings by any chance? try without paste? `sed -nE '/Begin|ReqURL|Varnish-Cache/ s/^-\s*(\S+)\s+(.*\S)\s*/\1="\2"/p'` and if it is still empty, post the output of `sudo varnishlog -c | cat -A` to question

Comment: With the last command, I got output as `Begin="req 363261 rxreq"\n
ReqURL="/sample/2"\n
RespHeader="X-Varnish-Cache: HIT"`. The \n is to indicate new lines, I am not able to add that in comment.
, I have updated my post with output of cat -A, please check.

Comment: sorry Sundeep, I did not get you.

Comment: you edited the comment... so the point I made is not valid now... anyway, since you seem to get result in separate lines, save that in a file and then try `paste -sd, file`

Comment: Yes, you are referring to ReqURL which I edited.  If I use paste again the output is empty. `sudo varnishlog -c | sed -nE '/Begin|ReqURL|Varnish-Cache/ s/^-\s*(\S+)\s+(.*\S)\s*/\1="\2"/p' | paste -sd,`

Comment: @user3181365: Refer my answer, which works too!

Comment: @user3181365 yeah, I have no idea why the perl+sed or sed+paste combo doesn't work.. so try to save the output of sed one into a file and call paste on that file...

Comment: @Sundeep, can you please tell me how to use the paste command separately?

Comment: I had pointed out earlier.. `paste -sd, file` where `file` is got from `sudo varnishlog -c | sed -nE '/Begin|ReqURL|Varnish-Cache/ s/^-\s*(\S+)\s+(.*\S)\s*/\1="\2"/p' > file`

Answer (score 0):

maybe this could help you;

```
sudo varnishlog -c | grep --line-buffered -E 'Begin|ReqURL|Varnish-Cache' |  sed -u 's/-   //;s/   */="/;s/$/"/' | tr '\n' ','
```